# Facebook Check In API

Tags: facebook, checkin

I am trying to implement Facebook Check in on my app similar to what Foursquare is doing. Instead of posting the place/location at the end user post message, I want to be displayed on the top title bar of the post.

e.g. Yen Pei Tay likes "<"something">" at "<"Place">"
     2 mins ago via "<"myApp">"

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare is using Open Graph Actions to publish their stories. For more information look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ .