# programmatically checkin to facebook from android app

Tags: android, facebook, checkin

How can I programmatically check in using android application like foresquare ? question describes it well
I  am not sure if it is supported by facebook API

Comment: Are you trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860067/facebook-check-in-api

Comment: Yes, you can do this programatically, ofcourse

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I will try it out and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below method:

```
private ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

    permissions.addAll(Arrays.asList("photo_upload","publish_checkins","publish_actions"));

    Session session = openActiveSession(YOUR ACTIVITY NAME.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    try {

                        if (getCurrentLocation() != null) {
                            location.put("latitude", new Double(YOUR LATITUDE));
                            location.put("longitude", new Double(YOUR LONGITUDE));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(YOUR ACTIVITY NAME.this, getString(R.string.facebook_location_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("place", id); 
                    params.putString("coordinates", location.toString());

                    if (edtMessage.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                        params.putString("message", message);
                    }
                    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(YOUR ACTIVITY.this,"Checkins success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    };
                    Request request = new Request(session, "me/checkins", params, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                    task.execute();
                }
            }

        }, permissions);
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I will try it out and get back to you